# wamp server wordprocess whole from begining up on filezilla

Tags: plugins

Please let me know how to upload a WordPress installation using Filezilla from a local installation. I have created a theme on a WAMP server locally. I have created a lot of pages and it runs successfully on localhost. Now i want to upload the files using FTP and upload the database also. Please help.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Couldn't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 parts to migrating WordPress.

1. Migrate your database content.
2. Migrate your files.

I suggest you install the [WP Migrate DB plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) and export your database from your local installation.

The plugin does a search, find and replace so your links don't break.

You will need to grab your live server path and enter these details along with your domain name into the plugin settings before exporting your database.

You can then create a new database in your web hosting accounts control panel and import the SQL file for your Database.

Make note of the new database name, username and password.

Open your wp-config.php file on your local installation of WordPress and change the database details with your new ones.

This connects your files to your new database on your live server.

Upload all your files from your local machine to your new server using FTP.